Generate camera trajectory with cameras' lookat following shape
I am trying with no avail to create a camera path that follows a lemniscate shape as shown in the figure. 
I do it in 3D but just set the vertical dimension (y) to a fixed number so really is 2D. the x and z coordinates are generated with a closed form function. I calculated the derivative of the function and that should give me the normal at each point. With the normal and a world UP axis I estimate the lookat direction and build a lookat matrix. However, this is not working for me. The camera does not turn properly at the lemniscate curves. Is there any other way to do this?
I have the 3D points of the lemniscate and I know world coordinates are  X-Right, Y-Down and Z-Forward.
This is the code:
    # Parameters
    a = 0.2  # Scale of the lemniscate

    # Create theta values
    theta1 = np.linspace(0.5*np.pi, 0.75*np.pi, 25)
    theta2 = np.linspace(0.75*np.pi, 1.25*np.pi, 80)
    theta3 = np.linspace(1.25*np.pi, 1.75*np.pi, 45)
    theta4 = np.linspace(1.75*np.pi, 2.25*np.pi, 80)
    theta5 = np.linspace(2.25*np.pi, 2.5*np.pi, 25)
    theta = np.concatenate((theta1, theta2, theta3, theta4, theta5))

    # Convert to Cartesian coordinates
    x = a * np.cos(theta) / (np.sin(theta)**2 + 1)
    z = a * np.cos(theta) * np.sin(theta) / (np.sin(theta)**2 + 1)
    y = a * 0.2 * np.cos(4*theta)
    Cs = np.stack((x, y, z)).T

    dx_dtheta = -a*(np.sin(theta) * (np.sin(theta) ** 2 + 2*np.cos(theta)**2 + 1)) / (np.sin(theta)**2 + 1)**2
    dz_dtheta = -a*(np.sin(theta)**4 + np.sin(theta)**2 + (np.sin(theta)**2-1)*np.cos(theta)**2) / (np.sin(theta)**2 + 1)**2
    dy_dtheta = - 4 * a * 0.2 * np.sin(4*theta)  # If I use this, it gets worse

    normal = np.stack((dx_dtheta, np.zeros_like(x), dz_dtheta)).T
    normal = normal / np.linalg.norm(normal, axis=1, keepdims=True)

    UP = np.array([0, -1, 0])[None, :]
    lookat = np.cross(normal, UP)
    lookat = lookat / np.linalg.norm(lookat, axis=1, keepdims=True)
    right = normal
    up = np.cross(right, lookat)
    up /= np.linalg.norm(up, axis=1, keepdims=True)

    Rs = np.concatenate((right, up, lookat), axis=1).reshape(-1, 3, 3).transpose(0, 2, 1)


Can you clarify the following question for me? (1) why is y related to theta, when you say but just set the vertical dimension (y) to a fixed number? (2) It seems that you are using Lemniscate of Bernoulli, and you present the curve in its parametric equation form. So, lets say if it is 2D. Taking the derivative of theta will end up in tangent vector on the x-z plane. If I understand it correctly, this should be the look-at vector (after normalization).

Sorry, You are right I set y related to theta. What I want is the lookat vector to be corresponding to the one in 2D, i.e. tangent vector on the x-z plane. Regardless if y is zero or not. That why in my normal I set y to zero normal = np.stack((dx_dtheta, np.zeros_like(x), dz_dtheta)).T.

Do not use lookat, use the Frenet frame's vectors as the basis vectors for the camera.

@Enigmatisms OMG you are right. Taking the derivative of theta will end up in tangent vector on the x-z plane. I was assuming that was the normal of a plane tangent to the line and so it pointed orthogonal to the lookat direction. Thanks for this. So the tangent line could also be interpreted as the normal of a plane orthogonal to the line?

Take a look at this figure: figure

Doesnt that plot contradict what you said? Taking the derivative of theta will end up in tangent vector on the x-z plane. In that plot the derivative is orthogonal to the tangent

In practice if you have a continuously twice differentiable regular curve $p(t) = (x(t), y(t), z(t))$ you can compute its velocity as $v(t) = \dot{p}(t) = \frac{dp}{dt}(t)$ and its acceleration as $a(t) = \dot{v}(t) = \ddot{p}(t)$ and use those to form an orthonormal basis (this wouod fail if $v(t)=0$ or $a(t)=0$). The velocity $v$ is tangent to the curve, but $a$ is not necessarily orthogonal to it, so if we wish to construct an orthonormal basis we need to orthonormalize those, e.g., by using Gram-Schmidt:
\begin{equation}
f_1(t) = \frac{v(t)}{\|v(t)\|_2}, \quad a_{\perp v}(t) = a(t) - (f_1(t)\cdot a(t))f_1(t), \quad f_2(t) = \frac{a(t)}{\|a(t)\|_2}.
\end{equation}
We can compute the third vector by using the cross product $f_3(t) = f_1(t)\times f_2(t)$. Now $f_1(t), f_2(t), f_3(t)$ form an orthonormal basis, and you can use the following for your camera matrix $C$ and view matrix $V$:
\begin{align}
C &= \begin{bmatrix}
| & | & | & | \\
f_1(t) & f_2(t) & f_3(t) & p(t) \\
| & | & | & | \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} F(t) & p(t) \\ 0^T & 1 \end{bmatrix}, \\
V &= C^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix} (F(t))^T & -(F(t))^Tp(t) \\ 0^T & 1 \end{bmatrix}.
\end{align}
Looking at your code the specific curve you have is parwmetrized as follows:
\begin{align}
x(t) = \frac{a \cos(t)}{1+\sin^2(t)}, \quad
y(t) = \frac{a \cos(t)\sin(t)}{1+\sin^2(t)},\quad
z(t) = b \cos(c t).
\end{align}
The first derivatives (the components of the velocity) can be computed in the following way (I derived this without pen and paper so you should double check it):
\begin{align}
\dot{x}(t) &= -\frac{a\sin(t)}{1+\sin^2(t)}-\frac{2a\cos^2(t)\sin(t)}{(1+\sin^2(t))^2}, \\
\dot{y}(t) &= \frac{a \cos(2t)}{1+\sin^2(t)} - \frac{a\sin^2(2t)}{2(1+\sin^2(t))^2}, \\
\dot{z}(t) &= -bc\sin(ct).
\end{align}
The second derivatives (components of the acceleration) are too tedious to compute so I suggest using wolfram alpha or some symbolic solver to do that for you.
